# Bootstrap form-inline and display:none

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an form-inline in Bootstrap and would like to have one of the form `<input>` controls be invisible until the user selects a particular option. When I display the page and the control is visible, all is well, but when I display it and the control has class="hide", and then I show it using jQuery.show(), the control appears on the next line.

It seems that the control's position doesn't get initialized properly if it has the "hide" class (display:none) when the page is first shown.

How do I get the control to initialize properly?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Try putting `JQuery.hide()` inside of your `document.ready()` function instead of initializing it as a class with `display:none`.